# How do priorities work in the *.services.yml YAML file?

Tags: 8

In `system.services.yml` and many other services files, one can find priorities like this:

```
services:

  ...

  path_processor.files:
    class: Drupal\system\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFiles
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }

  ...
```

Are these priorities similar to the weight-system we know from Drupal 7, where a low weight means earlier in the processing order. Or do priorities work the other way around, where the items with the highest priority are processed first?

I am asking because I could not find a source explaining this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drupal uses the [EventDispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) from Symfony and there the priority is used to control in which order the event listeners are triggered:

> An optional priority integer (higher equals more important and
>   therefore that the listener will be triggered earlier) that determines
>   when a listener is triggered versus other listeners (defaults to 0).
>   If two listeners have the same priority, they are executed in the
>   order that they were added to the dispatcher.

So the priority in D8 is exactly the opposite of the weight in D7.

The example you used in the question is not an event subscriber, but it uses the same concept of priorities.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I did not think of looking into Symfony's documentation.

Comment: Weight still exists in Drupal 8 for form/render elements and other things, otherwise correct.

Comment: @4k4 Question: is it guaranteed that all registered service will be executed (ordered higher to lower priority)? I had situation that while my service had lower priority it was not executed at all (was ignored) and when I raised priority it started working.

Comment: @MilanG, for Symfony events see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#stopping-event-flow-propagation. For tagged services this depends on the implementation. Path processing in this example runs all registered services. Theme negotiation demonstrates the opposite, running the registered negotiators until one returns a theme name.